# Access 2010 SQL subquery takes excessive time to run

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, ms-access-2010

I have written a query intended to return the number of minutes between transactions by users. MS Access takes 10 minutes to run it and I am unable to use the results. How can I improve its performance?

```
SELECT TestDataset.ID, TestDataset.OperatorID, TestDataset.DTCreated,
       (SELECT TOP 1 t2.DtCreated 
        FROM TestDataSet as t2
        WHERE t2.OperatorID = TestDataset.OperatorID AND t2.DtCreated < TestDataset.DtCreated
        ORDER BY t2.DtCreated,t2.ID
       ) as PreviousTransaction,
       Minute([DtCreated]-[PreviousTransaction]) AS Minutes
FROM TestDataset
ORDER BY TestDataset.OperatorID, TestDataset.DTCreated;
```

Comment: I'm surprised your query runs at all - t2 doesn't appear in the from clause or as an alias????

Comment: Edited my apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider switching databases, to something more powerful.  Most databases support ANSI standard window functions, which directly do what you want.

For your case, though, first try an index on `TestDataset(OperatorID, DtCreated, Id)`:

```
create index idx_TestDataset_OperatorID_DtCreated_Id on TestDataset(OperatorID, DtCreated, Id);
```

Comment: Although i was not to place indexes in through the statement above. added indexes through the Access GUI has drastically increased performance thank you.